# Can i install the applications disc of my snow leopard on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, ilife

I had Snow Leopard running on my MBP, now I just installed Lion on a Clean Installation and I noticed iLife is not in the installer.

Can I insert my snow leopard's application disc and install them on Lion ?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

I have verified that this works first hand.

Comment: I just want to confirm that the Snow Leopard DVD has iLife on it. I was thinking that it didn't.

Comment: There are three main types of Snow Leopard DVD's. Of the two that come with Mac's before Lion are the OS DVD that contains the OS X installer files AND drivers for that particular Mac. The other DVD that comes with a Mac is an "application disc" it contains iLife and Xcode I think. The third kind of Snow Leopard disc is the retail copy which you might buy off a shelf and it ONLY has the OS X installer files and NO drivers or iLife applications.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. My Mac came with Leopard and I upgraded to SL, so I have the Application Disc from 10.5. I put it in my computer to see what was on it and found iWeb, Garageband, iDVD, iPhoto, and iMovie. Oddly enough, iDVD and iPhoto are grayed out.